# Are there video tutorials on how to analyze the memory footprint of an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

Are there good video tuts that show how to use this Object Alloc instrument to figure out if my objects and other stuff get freed from memory? Also, I have a bunch of C code and use Core Audio, so those are not really objects but still heavy in memory. Would like to know more about that Object Alloc instrument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the WWDC 2009 videos, sessions 414: "iPhone Performance Optimization with Instruments" and 415: "Optimizing Performance on iPhone" both show how to analyze memory issues on iPhone.

If you are a registered iPhone developer, you should also have access to the iPhone Tech Talk videos through the iPhone Dev Center, one of which is titled "Maximizing iPhone App Performance".  This video has a good overview of memory-related issues on the iPhone, and does show off the ObjectAlloc instrument for a bit.

Alberto Aroaz gives a nice walkthrough of Instruments in his "[Secrets of iPhone performance optimization](http://www.oredev.org/prod/oredev/site.nsf/docsbycodename/session?opendocument&sid=4DB5D96BAD6E978EC12575DD0051736D&track=022317E241DB32A0C12575A500496F27&day=4)" talk.

The [Instruments User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652) is the go-to text reference for using Instruments, so I'd read that cover-to-cover.

Finally, I taught a class on using Instruments and Shark to tune your iPhone applications, but the video for that is not yet up on iTunes U.  It should be available for free sometime in the next few months.  In the meantime, I provide a text overview of the instruments you can use for memory and performance tuning in [my class notes](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/AdvancediPhoneApps.zip) (VoodooPad format).